# not correct value inserting in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have php file that is pulling data from a server, it is correctly parsed , anyways

this is a sample data:

```
"headerTotalValue":"2,338,848.0000000000" , "headerTotalVolume":"279,000.0000000000"
```

Now in my script the values are correctly display as is but whenever I am inserting them in my DB it only stores as **`2`** and **`279`** but I want them as **`2,338,848`** and **`279,000`**

The column is **`Value INT(12)`** and **`Volume INT(12)`**

Any thoughts what's wrong happening here.

Answer (score 1):

1.First thing you posting Floting point value but database column as `INT`

2.Second you use comma(,) its `CHAR` so you can avoid coma or use `VARCHAR` in DB

Comment: Don't use `VARCHAR` for integers of floats. Store integers as integers, floats as floats. And let output & format routines be processed in application. DB has _nothing to do_ with them. It should only store data in proper way (i.e. with data type, to which that data belongs logically)

Comment: @AlmaDo good point which means I need to do something like typecasting in php?

Comment: Yes, convert your data in application and store it properly in DB. That will save you lots of time in future

Comment: @Drixson Oseña for  your refererence  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/floating-point-types.html

Answer (score 1):

You can't use ',' and '.' in an `INT` field. 
Integer cannot take floating-point numbers, only whole numbers.

Reformat your data to read like `2338848` and `279000` and use `INT`.
If you need the digits after the comma, change your field to `DOUBLE` and use numbers like `2338848.0` and `279000.0`.

Further reading about data types:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-types.html
- http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes_general.asp

EDIT: 
As Mani has commented, here the direct link to the floating-point section of the MySQL Manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/floating-point-types.html

Answer (score 0):

Your column definition should be using something like `decimal(17, 10)` instead of `int(12)`

Read [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/floating-point-types.html) from more info.